# Get the current operating system's default browser & open a web page with it?

Tags: dart

With a local client side application, with

```dart
import 'dart:io';
```

I see no way to load up the consumers current default browser and then load a web page. (Locally stored HTML or a website)

I've searched the API documentation at http://api.dartlang.org yet have found no easy way.

Is there any way of doing this yet? 
Preferably similar to the [Desktop class in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a function for that. You can fill a [new feature request](http://dartbug.com/new).

If you need a workaround, you can deal with the [Process](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/Process.html) and [Platform](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/Platform.html) classes.

- on Windows you should be able to [launch the default browser](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/5bf91e62-7be9-4f1d-9bac-5b2a4dd8ced7/) with `start ${url}`.
- on linux, you can [do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19919/command-to-open-a-url) with `xdg-open ${url}` if `xdg-open` is present.
- in other cases, there should be a solution...

Here is a sample :

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  final url = "http://dartlang.org";
  if (Platform.operatingSystem == 'windows') {
    Process.run("start", [url]);
  } else if (Platform.operatingSystem == 'linux') {
    Process.run("xdg-open", [url]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree, it'd be great if you filed a feature request on dartbug.com. If you do, add a link here.

Comment: Created the issue, wasn't too sure on the format, but I'm sure the intelligent Dartisans will understand regardless. The issue's at http://dartbug.com/7402

Comment: They suggested creating a package for this... someone had to do it, so here we go: https://pub.dev/packages/open_url

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I find the `runInShell` flag needs to be set:

```
Process.run("start", [url], runInShell: true);
```

(at least on Windows 7).

I'm surprised that someone has not created a package to reliably invoke the default browser on all platforms.